# how to display a edittext when radiobutton is clicked in android

Tags: android

I have a program which computes perimeter, circumference, an area of different shapes like, square, circle, rectangle and soon. Any help with enabling the radiobutton to display an edittext to write the measurements.

Comment: have you done any things from your end ?

Comment: havent yet, i cant find any topic in the internet which relates to showing of edit text when radio button is checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check below code don't use as it is, its just reference

inyourxml.xml

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/groupRadio"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/app_big_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/app_normal_margin"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minHeight="30dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/circumferenceRadio"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_selector_background"
        android:button="@null"
        android:checked="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/choice_yes"
        android:textColor="@drawable/tab_selector_text" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/perimeterRadio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_selector_background"
        android:button="@null"
        android:checked="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/choice_no"
        android:textColor="@drawable/tab_selector_text" />
</RadioGroup>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/perimeterEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/app_normal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/app_normal_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/action_bar_background"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/circumferenceEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/app_normal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/app_normal_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/action_bar_background"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
```

inyourjava.java

```
RadioGroup groupRadio=(RadioGroup)rootView.findViewById(R.id.groupRadio);
EditText   perimeterEditText=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.perimeterEditText);
EditText  circumferenceEditText=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.circumferenceEditText);
groupRadio.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

          if(checkedId==R.id.circumferenceRadio)
          {
            circumferenceEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            perimeterEditText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          }
          else if(checkedId==R.id.perimeterRadio)
          {
            perimeterEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            circumferenceEditText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[Hide a EditText & make it visible by clicking a menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622517/hide-a-edittext-make-it-visible-by-clicking-a-menu)
in case of menu ... you can declare setvisibility in xml and make it hide... then programatically make it visible...hope this helps

Comment: Please try this ...and then ask.. no offense