# Button with function of hiding and showing text

Tags: android, button, show-hide

I am trying to implement a Button which shows a text when pressed and hides it when pressed again.
I am working in the design tab in Android Studio 2.2.2.

Does anyone know how this could be done in a simple way? Can it be done in the design tab of the activity_main.xml file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide a EditText & make it visible by clicking a menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622517/hide-a-edittext-make-it-visible-by-clicking-a-menu)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code:

```
boolean visible = true;

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (visible) {
                textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                visible = false;
            } else {
                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                visible = true;
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I am not a coder so I really don't understand. Is this in the Java view?

Comment: If you are not a coder, then how are you developing android app in first place??? And yes this is in java

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.setOnClickListener(){

@Override
public View onClick(View view){
   if(!((button.getText().toString()).equals(""))){
       button.setText("")
   }else{
       button.setText(text);
   }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting the text on the button to be toggled, then the following will do that.

```
private Button button;
private String txt = "default button text";

protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setText(txt); // Or define it in the XML layout
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(b.getText().toString()) 
                b.setText(txt);
            else 
                b.setText("");
        }
    });
}
```

If you are trying to toggle the text of some other view, just replace the logic in the click event.

Comment: This only works if the `android:text` attribute is not set in layout file

Comment: True. Updated anyway

Answer (score -1):

You Have to write this code in java file to make text view or anything too visible

```
Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello);
            t1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

And Write This Code In Xml File to you particular hiding thing

```
android:visibility="gone"
```